# Search function not working in Django / Bootstrap

Tags: django, search

I am facing problems in search functionality of Django. the function is as follows:

```
 def search(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        query = request.GET.get('query','')
    allPosts = Post.objects.filter(Q(title__icontains=query) | Q(content__icontains=query))
    return render(request, 'dn/search.html', {'allPosts':allPosts, 'query':query})
```

the search form is as under:

```
<form class ="{% url 'search' %} d-flex" method="get">
<input class="form-control me-2" type="text" name="query" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
<button class=" text-white text-uppercase fw-bold btn btn-outline-primary light border-1 rounded-pill border-white border border-1" type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

the search page is as under:

```
{%extends 'dn/base.html'%}

{% block title %} Search Results | active {% endblock title %}


{% block content %} 
    <div class="container">
        {% if allposts %}
            {% for query in allposts %}
                <div class="row">
                    <div class = "col md-12">    
                        <h3>{{query.title}}</h3> <br> 
                    </div>                    
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <p>{{query.content}} </p>
                    </div> 
                </div>  
            {% endfor %} 
        {% else %}
        <p><h3> No Search Results </h3></P>
        {% endif %} 
    </div>
{%endblock%}
```

However, while searching anything in the system is not showing the results.

can you please guide me what i am missing to get the results.

Thanking you.

Regards
SSA

Comment: Your `search(request)` does not really care about POST or other requests. You don't have a `query` variable at all time but you still wanna use it later in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Variable names in the template are case-sensitive.

Use:

```
{% if allPosts %}
    {% for query in allPosts %}
```

instead of:

```
{% if allposts %}
    {% for query in allposts %}
```

Comment: still not working. basically the website is RTL. Thanks for the corrections

Comment: Have you debugged the code? What can you see in your query? Any errors?

Comment: after debugging this error is shown

 File "C:\Users\................\Desktop\myproject\dn\templates\dn\search.html", line 1
    {%extends 'dn/base.html'%}
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax